# Is it possible to download files only with certain names automatically from Telegram?

Tags: javascript, automation, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I would like to download certain files from a Telegram Group which are uploaded with same name(with date attached at end) everyday at some point of time.

I have to download them every one by one by clicking on download button as there are some other stuff which is not needed for me..

So,I would like to automate this process.Is it possible to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The Telegram bot API contains that information. 
You get an message object. In this message object the member document is set to the document object. In this object you find the meta information about the file suche like name an mine type. With the method getFile and the ID of the document object you can download the file.

Here the links.

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message message object

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#document document object

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getfile getFile method

I hope this helps.